# How to run PowerShell in x64 or x86 using C#?

Tags: c#, powershell

I'm using this C# code to read my installed programs using PowerShell.

I need it to read both x64 and x86 registry through PowerShell, how am I doing this?

Is there a way to redirect? or maybe run PowerShell in x64 and then x86?

```
public void conf() {
process p1 = new Process();
ProcessStartInfo psi1 = new ProcessStartInfo("powershell", "Get-ItemProperty HKLM:\\Software\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Uninstall\\* | Select-Object DisplayName");
psi1.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
psi1.CreateNoWindow = true;
p1.StartInfo = psi1;
p1.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
p1.StartInfo.Verb = "runas";
p1.Start();
string output = p1.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
Console.WriteLine(output);
p1.WaitForExit(400);
}
```

Comment: I don't think the `HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\` key is affected by the x64 redirection. That powershell command should list both x64 and x86 programs. What is exactly the problem? Do you see only x64 or only x86 programs?

Comment: It doesn't list the x64 programs. when I'm changing platform to x64 from "Any CPU" through Configuration Manager in Visual Studio, it lists only x64 programs. when I'm changing to x86, it lists only x86 programs.

Comment: That's right, I didn't think it was redirected... I'll make some tests and give you an answer in a minute

Comment: By the way, why do you need PowerShell for this if the only think you  are doing is reading Registry? C# Microsoft.Win32.Registry can do the same think. Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(@"SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall")

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should do if your process is running in x64 (or it's an x86 process running on an x86 OS).

```
bool is64 = IntPtr.Size == 8;
var cmdline = "Get-ItemProperty HKLM:\\Software\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Uninstall\\* " 
       + (is64 ? ",HKLM:\\Software\\Wow6432Node\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Uninstall\\*" : "") 
       + " | Select-Object DisplayName";
ProcessStartInfo psi1 = new ProcessStartInfo("powershell", cmdline);
```

This won't work if the process is a 32-bit process running on an x64 OS, but for .NET, it should work with `AnyCPU` as long as you don't choose "prefer 32-bit"

#### Update

If you are only aiming at getting the display names, there might be "display-name duplicates" (in both registry keys)... so you can just remove them from the output. This will remove duplicates and sort:

```
var result = new StringBuilder();
var resultArr = output.Split(new string[] { Environment.NewLine }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).Distinct().ToArray();
Array.Sort(resultArr, StringComparer.InvariantCulture);
foreach (string s in resultArr)
    result.AppendLine(s);
output = result.ToString();
```

#### Update 2

If you don't want to mangle with processes and capturing output, you can install the `System.Management.Automation` nuget package and use powershell directly.

The whole equivalent program would be:

```
PowerShell ps = PowerShell.Create();
ps.AddCommand("Get-ItemProperty");
var parm = new List<string> {
     @"HKLM:\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\*"
};
if(IntPtr.Size == 8)
  parm.Add(@"HKLM:\Software\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\*");
var pso = ps.Invoke(parm);
var result = new StringBuilder();
foreach (var ob in pso)
{
  if(ob.Members["DisplayName"] != null)
    result.AppendLine(ob.Members["DisplayName"].Value.ToString());
}
Console.WriteLine(result.ToString());
```

This should be better than calling the process :-)

Comment: Thanks so much. But what if I'm running my process in a x84 computer? Is there any solution?

Comment: What do you mean with x84? You can't run x64 processes on an x86 computer, and you can't install x64 programs in an x86 computer. So this should work as long as your process is `AnyCPU` and does not "prefer 32-bit"

Comment: @Tom there is no x84 architecture as far as I know

Comment: What I haven't figured out with the registry is how to read x64 installed programs from an x86 process in an x64 operating system. You can do that using the WMI, but I can't seem to figure out how to do it using the registry

Comment: I need to run this program on some 64 or x86 computers to figure out what programs are installed, so I don't think it would work for me.

Comment: @Tom this should work fine for your scenario if you compile your program with `AnyCPU` without "prefer 32 bit". Will list all installed programs on either x86 or x64 computers if built that way

Comment: Weird, it shows me the same output twince, when I did it, for some reason it redirects to the same place.

Comment: Tom, shows the same output twice in x64, in x86, or in both?

Comment: I'm on a x64 computer, I did "AnyCPU"

Comment: @Tom have you checked (with regedit) that there are not several keys with the same `DisplayName`? You could just remove the duplicates if all that you aim for is the display names. I get *some* duplicates, but I get them even if listing just one of the reg keys... they are just there in the registry

Comment: It works good when I'm doing x64 platform and not "AnyCPU", and it's exactly the same content when on "AnyCPU" which is weird. Maybe Visual Studio chooses x86 when I'm doing "AnyCPU"?

Comment: @Tom when doing `AnyCPU` do you have `prefer 32 bit` checked? As I explained in my post, that'd be a problem

Comment: @Tom check my update, if you want to sort and avoid any "display name" duplicates

Comment: @Tom I added yet another update which shows how to use `PowerShell` cmdlets directly in C#, no need to call the process and capture the output